# Why is the spectrum of the momentum operator continuous for states containing 2 or more particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, momentum, eigenvalue

Consider a free theory and let $P^\mu = (H, \mathbf{P})$ be the 4-momentum operator. Since $P_\mu P^\mu = m^2$ is a Lorentz scalar, we get the relation $H^2 - |\mathbf{P}|^2 = m^2$. Here $H$ must be an eigenvalue $E$ of the Hamiltonian so that the momentum is on shell. With this requirement we get that the spectrum of the one particle state is all combinations of scalars $E$ and vectors $\mathbf{P}$ such that $E^2 - |\mathbf{P}|^2 = m^2$, which is a hyperboloid. We also have that the vacuum is the point at the origin. This describes the spectrum of $P^\mu$ for systems consisting of $n = 0, 1$ particles.

Assuming the above is all correct, I am unclear on why states consisting of two or more particles form a continuum in a rest frame with zero momenta. This is stated in Peskin & Schroeder and visualized in Figure 7.1 (page 213). A similar question was asked in another question ([Why do the eigenvalues of the 4-momentum operator organize themselves into hyperboloids?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/776550/why-do-the-eigenvalues-of-the-4-momentum-operator-organize-themselves-into-hyper)), from which I know this somehow follows from boosts and Lorentz invariance, but I still do not fully understand why there is a continuum.

Can anyone explain why there is a continuum for $n \geq 2$ states and why there is a "bound state" between the $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ states in the figure? In a rest frame with two particle, why does $E^2 - |\mathbf{P}|^2 = 4m^2$?

Comment: Well, if you have two particles, then the energy of a "combined" particle can be lower than the sum of the rest energies of both particles, hence there can be bound state, which are expected below $2m$. BTW: Without the book (at hand) it might be hard to follow. It might be worth to add e.g. a sketch of the relevant figures... (I don't know the rules regarding copy-pasting graphs from books here on PSE)#

Comment: @TobiasFünke Why/how can the combined particle have energy lower than their sum? If the moderators are ok with me posting a picture of the figure I will add it to my post.

Comment: Well, this then means that it takes energy to separate the particles (and hence the name: *bound* states). Take e.g. the hydrogen atom or molecules in general.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Oh yes I see now, thank you. But since this is a free theory wouldn't such a state necessarily have minimum energy $4m^2$ since there is no interaction?

Comment: Don't they talk about interacting theories?!

Comment: @TobiasFünke I was so confused by the figure that I completely forgot we are talking about interacting theories, sorry about that. So I know understand where the $4m^2$ and the bound state curve comes from. The only point I now need to figure out is why $n \geq 2$ is a continuum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why there is a continuous spectrum for multiparticle states look at a n-particle state with zero total momentum, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{P} = \sum_i \mathbf{p}_i = 0.
\end{equation*}
The energy of this state is then just
\begin{equation*}
E = \sum_i \sqrt{m^2 + \mathbf{p}_i^2}.
\end{equation*}
Since the $\mathbf{p}_i^2$ can be chosen arbitrarily as long as they still sum to 0, this gives you a continuum. This energy has a lower bound of $E = 2\sqrt{m}$ corresponding to two particles at rest so the contiuum starts there.

Comment: Thank you very much!